# Water supplier ontology

Tags: data-mining

I am new in this world, I am going to start working on my final degree project about data mining. I need to look for an **ontology related with water supplier** companies.

I mean, I have words like: SuppliedWater, RegisteredWater, LengthSupplyingNetwork...

I am looking at [lod-cloud](http://lod-cloud.net/), but I don't know where to start looking for this.

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used [this](http://catalog.data.gov/) website, since I found it easier to found any ontology.
For example I found [this one](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/water-consumption-in-the-new-york-city-3d2f0), very similar to what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, Linked Open Vocabulary might help. E.g. https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/terms?q=%22water+supply%22